# Arduino Mega Pull-up on Analog input

Tags: arduino, pullup

does Arduino Mega2560 (based on ATMega 2560) has an input pull-up on analog inputs? Can I set the input pull-up as usual by software?

The reason is that I need to use the analog pins as extra digital inputs.

Comment: The reason is I am using an analog pin as digital pin and I need a pull-up on that pin

Comment: If you are using it as a digital input, then it is NOT an "analog pin". So the premise of your question is not valid.

Comment: I need to read a dry contact with analog input pin, the reason for using the analog pin instead of a digital one is that is more convenient for the PCB layout to add a screw pin terminal near that input pin. I need a pull-up as I am reading a dry contact and so I would like to avoid floating readings. This is the reason I am asking if exists an internal pull-up to analog inputs. I know that would be better to use a digital pin, but the PCB is produced and I need to find an alternative. I hope that now the problem is clear. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A pull up makes no sense on an analog input.

[The Atmega 2560 datasheet ADC section(page 268)](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2549-8-bit-avr-microcontroller-atmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf) makes no mention of pull ups on the analog inputs.

The digital section (page 67) shows the switchable pull ups.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the pin as a digital input, you can enable the internal pull-up resistor for that pin.

This is true regardless of whether the same pin also has the ability to be used as an analog input.

Answer (score 2):

The internal pull-up resistors on analog inputs are mentioned in a tutorial:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogInputPins

The following tutorials use this in their sketches:

http://www.edisondev.net/Arduino/ArduinoAnalogPullup
http://tronixstuff.com/2011/01/11/tutorial-using-analog-input-for-multiple-buttons/

Answer (score 1):

Typically "pull-up" is a function used for binary inputs (either high or low). It is not clear why one would even need "pull-up" in an an analog input? If you did need some sort of pull-up, it would be arranged externally since there is no way of offering a pull-up internally that would be appropriate for all analog sources.